# Method in SoapUI request to generate random alpha numeric string

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a method to generate an 8 characters alpha numeric string.

```
log.info(
    new Random().with {
    (1..8).collect { (('A'..'Z')+('0'..'9')).join()[ nextInt( (('A'..'Z')+('0'..'9')).join().length() ) ] }.join()
  })
```

I ran it as test case set up script and it returns:

```
Thu Sep 18 10:37:18 NZST 2014:INFO:L7S76IP1
```

When I include this in the test request as one of the attribute:

```
${new Random().with {(1..8).collect { (('A'..'Z')+('0'..'9')).join()[ nextInt( (('A'..'Z')+('0'..'9')).join().length() ) ] }.join()}}
```

Then it did not return the random string as I expected.

Can you please help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: What's returned then? Any exception etc?

Comment: doesn't the randomizer need a warm-up? usually it returns the very same value on the 1st run

Comment: It works fine with groovy console. No idea how to help You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **equal** sign in the property expansion, like so: `${=new Random .....}`

Also, you might want to look at [Apache RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html).